# How to read a public inbox archive in Thunderbird / Alpine?

Tags: email, git, thunderbird, alpine-mail

I would like to read an archive of one mailing list located at https://lore.kernel.org/. It appears they use something called a "`public-inbox`" format, based on `git`. Unfortunately, trying to checkout such archive produces lots of separate eml files that quickly clutter the filesystem, and the mbox archives are only provided on a per-thread basis, so there is no convenient way to read those on a conventional email client like Thunderbird or Alpine... or is there?

Answer (score 1):

The public-inbox software includes an NNTP server, whose address is listed at the footer of each mailing list's "thread list" page. For the Kernel.org instance, click "mirroring instructions".

For example, linux-nfs is available via NNTP at:

```
nntp://nntp.lore.kernel.org/org.kernel.vger.linux-nfs
```

Thunderbird may or may not recognize `nntp://` URLs. In case it doesn't:

1. Add a new "News" or "Newsgroups" account to Thunderbird.
2. Specify `nntp.lore.kernel.org` as the server name.
3. Right-click the new account in the main sidebar and open "Subscribe…".
4. Subscribe to the `org.kernel.vger.linux-nfs` newsgroup.